# Angular 2 ngFor object property change not updated its view

Tags: angular2-changedetection

I have did the following

```
     <div *ngFor="let item of documentData">
         <polymer-component [data]="item"></polymer-component>
        </div>
    <button (click)="ChangePropertyValue()">ChangePropertyValue</button>

    ChangePropertyValue(){
       this.documentData[0].documentname="Document changed";    
    }
    ngOnInit(){
      this.documentData={"documentname":"Document"}
    }
```

Polymer-Component has properties such as

- documentname

When firing the ChangePropertyValue() , the object and its property is being updated but not its view. Please provide solution as soon as possible.

I have also tried ChangeDetectorRef,still it results nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try running inside of angular's zone

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {

}

ChangePropertyValue(){
     this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.documentData[0].documentname="Document changed"
     })   
}
```